# Parsing dates in LibreOffice Calc - is there a better/easier way?

Tags: spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc

I have a string of this particular format:

```
DD/MMM/YY HH:MM AM/PM
```

e.g.

```
03/Nov/14 9:00 AM
```

I could not find figure out how to make [Calc](http://www.libreoffice.org/discover/calc/) recognize it as a date so I had to do the following for a date string in **B2**:

```
=DATEVALUE(
    CONCATENATE(
        2000+MID(B2,8,2),
        "-",
        IF(MID(B2,4,3)="Jan",1,
            IF(MID(B2,4,3)="Feb",2,
                IF(MID(B2,4,3)="Mar",3,
                    IF(MID(B2,4,3)="Apr",4,
                        IF(MID(B2,4,3)="May",5,
                            IF(MID(B2,4,3)="Jun",6,
                                IF(MID(B2,4,3)="Jul",7,
                                    IF(MID(B2,4,3)="Aug",8,
                                        IF(MID(B2,4,3)="Sep",9,
                                            IF(MID(B2,4,3)="Oct",10,
                                                IF(MID(B2,4,3)="Nov",11,
                                                    IF(MID(B2,4,3)="Dec",12,""
        )))))))))))),
        "-",
        MID(B2,1,2)
    )
)
+
TIMEVALUE(
    IF(MID(B2,8,1)=" ",RIGHT(B2,7),RIGHT(B2,8))
)
```

or on one line:

```
=DATEVALUE(CONCATENATE(2000+MID(B2,8,2),"-",IF(MID(B2,4,3)="Jan",1,IF(MID(B2,4,3)="Feb",2,IF(MID(B2,4,3)="Mar",3,IF(MID(B2,4,3)="Apr",4,IF(MID(B2,4,3)="May",5,IF(MID(B2,4,3)="Jun",6,IF(MID(B2,4,3)="Jul",7,IF(MID(B2,4,3)="Aug",8,IF(MID(B2,4,3)="Sep",9,IF(MID(B2,4,3)="Oct",10,IF(MID(B2,4,3)="Nov",11,IF(MID(B2,4,3)="Dec",12,"")))))))))))),"-",MID(B2,1,2)))+TIMEVALUE(IF(MID(B2,8,1)=" ",RIGHT(B2,7),RIGHT(B2,8)))
```

and then change the type of the cell containing the formula to Date and chose the desirable format.

All in all a quite involved process. **Is there a more automated way?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use some sort of "lookup table" to translate the month names to dates (this solution is based on a [solution proposed for the opposite operation - translate numbers to month names](https://www.mail-archive.com/users@openoffice.org/msg87307.html))

Just put the month names one after each other into a column on your spreadsheet, and define a named range on those cells (e.g. `Monthnames`). Now, you can determine the month's number using `=MATCH("Dec",Monthnames,0)` which results in `12`:

[image]

With such a table, you could replace the `IF` statements by a single `MATCH` call:

> `=DATEVALUE(CONCATENATE(MID(A2,8,2),"/",MATCH(MID(A2,4,3),Monthnames,0),"/",MID(A2,1,2)))`

or on multiple lines:

> `=DATEVALUE(
>            CONCATENATE(
>                  MID(A2,8,2),
>                  "/",
>                  MATCH(
>                       MID(A2,4,3),
>                       Monthnames,
>                       0
>                  ),
>                  "/",
>                  MID(A2,1,2)
>             )
>       )`

The formula above constructs a valid date value from your example strings:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use MONTH to extract month value with dummy dd, yy values:

```
=DATEVALUE(CONCATENATE(MID(A2,8,2),"/",MONTH("1"&MID(A2,4,3)&"1"),"/",MID(A2,1,2)))
```

Comment: Remember to properly format your answer. Use a right angle bracket `>` before each line of a block quote, and indent code blocks with four spaces.

Comment: Gary, your formula does not work out from the box but I can see what you mean, [LibreOffice manual](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/MONTH) to the rescue, e.g. `=MONTH(CONCATENATE("2000","-",MID(A2,4,3),"-","1"))` or shorter `=MONTH("1999"&"-"&MID(B2,4,3)&"-"&"1")` (didn't know that concatenate trick). Clever, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add zero to the date. It worked for me when the date was in text format (ie had an apostrophe in front of the value) for data imported from a data file.